# Set Lubuntu 20_04LXQT theme to dark

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, themes, gui, lxqt

In Lubuntu 20_04(LXQT), you have "dark" in preferences -> lxqt settings -> appearance.

In LXQT Theme, the default is Lubuntu Arc. 'Dark' sets the Menu in the bottom left and the task bar to black background and white font. Can I change all programms such as chromium, etc. to this color scheme, not just the menu? I am aware that I can change each programme, if available, to dark mode.

Comment: Only programs that follow/use the Qt settings made by LXQt will follow the set theme. There are settings for Qt, GTK2 & GTK3, however the LXQt theme impacts panel & notifications as explained in the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html

Comment: FYI:  https://phab.lubuntu.me/rMANUALd2f3690b7570946b78cddcb190c009736d9d71e1 via https://phab.lubuntu.me/T176 , thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lubuntu manual https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html in the section on Appearance states

> The tab for LXQt Theme lets you change how the panel and notifications appear. To change the theme left click on the theme name to change the theme. To the left of the theme name there is a small preview of the panel and the default button for the panel. The checkbox Override user-defined wallpaper changes your wallpaper to one that comes with the LXQt theme.

You're asking it to do more than it's intended to do, you can change themes used by applications, as described earlier in that page of the manual.

Answer (score 4):

Having wished to have a dark theme on Lubuntu 20.04, I have installed the Kvantum Manager.

In LXQt settings, I choose the "kvantum" widget theme :
[image: LXQt Appearance configuration - Widget Style tab]

Then in LXQt settings, I open the Kvantum Manager and select a dark theme :
[image: Kvantum Manager with dark theme selected]

Click "Use this theme". Job done.

Comment: After doing all this, it still was showing light theme when opening applications. I had to shut down Firefox and every other GTK app. And then they would open up with the new theme. :)